# duplicate record occur in mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, mybatis

There are some duplicate record in mysql. It's seem some special condition will trigger it. I have checked my code, but didn't reason out.

spring-boot2.1, mybatis2.1, mysql5.7

```
 @Override
    public int addSalesmanUser(ShareSalesmanUser shareSalesmanUser) {
        if (shareSalesmanUser.getUserId() == null || shareSalesmanUser.getSalesmanId() == null) {
            throw new ParamError("param error");
        }

        Example example = new Example(ShareSalesmanUser.class);
        example.createCriteria().andEqualTo("userId", shareSalesmanUser.getUserId());
        List<ShareSalesmanUser> list = shareSalesmanUserMapper.selectByExample(example);
        if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
            throw new ServerError("bound yet");
        }
        shareSalesmanUser.setCreateTime(new Date());
        shareSalesmanUser.setUpdateTime(new Date());
        int rs = shareSalesmanUserMapper.insertSelective(shareSalesmanUser);
        return rs;
    }
```

```
user_salesman_id  user_id  salesman_id  register_bysalesman create_time update_time delete_time
253 311 7   0   2019-01-05 09:23:46.612000  2019-01-05 09:23:46.612000  
248 310 7   0   2019-01-05 09:21:18.483000  2019-01-05 09:21:18.483000  
249 310 7   0   2019-01-05 09:21:18.488000  2019-01-05 09:21:18.488000  
250 310 7   0   2019-01-05 09:21:18.492000  2019-01-05 09:21:18.492000  
251 310 7   0   2019-01-05 09:21:18.496000  2019-01-05 09:21:18.496000  
252 310 7   0   2019-01-05 09:21:18.511000  2019-01-05 09:21:18.511000
```

[service code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQmQ7.png)

[java entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjIQC.png)

[mysql record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMFc7.png)

Comment: I have no idea, could anyone give some hints?

Comment: one account will bind one salesman, and bind by himself. so it may not the concurrent problem.

Comment: There are no duplicates here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks very much like concurrency problem. The code does two things:

1. fetch all associations between user and salesman
2. if there is no association create one

The problem happens when multiple concurrent calls to `addSalesmanUser` are executed. In this case the first step may fetch empty list for multiple concurrent calls because at the moment of its execution no other records are inserted. So the second step would insert multiple records.

You wrote that this is not an issue, but please look at the creation time column, the difference is 4 ms which suggests that it was a concurrent execution.

The simplest way to handle this is to enforce the constraint that for given user there should be only one salesman in the database. Create a unique constraint for `(user_id, salesman_id)` pair. With it in place only one call will be successful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know the way that creating a unique constraint for `(user_id, salesman_id)`. But I want to know how it will trigger the concurrency problem. It may not possible cause of only the user himself can do the action. How could it happen? And we have prohibited double click on the front-end. Or because the worse network condition of the user? Thanks again, Roman Konoval.

Comment: You get multiple records in DB. So this code is executed multiple times almost at the same time. At some level multiple invocations are done. Either you have the bug in the front-end and it sends multiple requests (check access logs if this is the case) or there's some logic in the client of your service (enable logging in mybatis to see queries executed preferably with the thread id included) that executes `addSalesmanUser` multiple times concurrently.

Comment: Thannnnnnnnnnnks. I have found the problem source by checked the nginx log. The one front-end sent multiple requests, so it make a concurrent problem. Thanks for your time, Roiman Konoval.